# Inkscape - how to set stroke style from unix command line

Tags: svg, inkscape

I am writing an app which is using svg to plot points on an image.  The image is originally coming in as a pdf and I am converting it to a .svg file using Inkscape in unix with the command:

`inkscape –l convertedImage.svg baseImage.pdf`

Then in my html using the converted image in my svg tag.

```
<svg>
    <image x=”100” y=”100” width=”500” height=”500”
    xlink:href=”/my/location/convertedImage.svg”></image>
    …
</sig>
```

My problem is that the image lines are too light after the conversion.  If I open the Inkscape GUI, I can select the image and in the 'Stroke Style' tab increase the width by 1px.  Doing it this way makes the image look how I would like it too, but I need to be able to do it in a programmatic way because I am running this command over many pdf files every day.

Is there a way I can either:

1. Include the Stroke Style Width setting in the inkscape unix command?
2. Somehow set it after the fact in the svg img tag using css?

Comment: Wouldn't something like `svg * { stroke-width: 1px }` work? If it doesn't work with the embedded image, it will definitely work if you inline the svg.

Comment: @DaggNabbit That CSS won't work. Even if the SVG is inlined it will most likely not work because it would be overridden by the style attributes that Inkscape sets on each element. However, `svg * {stroke-width: 1px !important}` might do the job. But I think there are better solutions.

Comment: @Marianna Are the line widths O.K. in the PDF? If so, then try a different converter, namely `pdf2svg`. If that doesn't help, I'd suggest some SVG cleanup as a second step, which is a good idea anyway because Inkscape can produce some pretty blown up SVG markup. Depending on whether this is a one-off task or you do this conversion routinely, manual or automated cleanup would be preferable. For better being able to help you with cleaning up I'd ask for at least a snippet of the converted SVG.

Comment: The line widths look okay in the pdf but I think it is just because PDF displays them differently.  I also tried imagemagick to png with the same results.  I know Inkscape has the capability to do what I want, but I just need that access from the command line

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post a link to a sample PDF?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SVG is an XML format, so you can fix it with an XML transformation like this:

shell> **xsltproc svglinewidth.xsl convertedImage.svg > fixedImage.svg**

where svglinewidth.xsl contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>

    <xsl:param name="stroke-width">1px</xsl:param>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|text()|*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@style[contains(., 'stroke-width:')]">
        <xsl:variable name="before" select="substring-before(.,'stroke-width:')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="rest" select="substring-after(.,'stroke-width:')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="after" select="substring-after($rest,';')"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="style">
            <xsl:value-of select="$before"/>
            <xsl:text>stroke-width:</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$stroke-width"/>
            <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$after"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|text()">
        <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will replace all occurrences of stroke-width in style attributes with the value stroke-width:1px,

To specify another width, you can pass a parameter to xsltproc like this:

shell> xsltproc **--stringparam stroke-width 5px** svglinewidth.xsl convertedImage.svg > fixedImage.svg

xsltproc is available for almost any platform. Linuxes have it as package, for Unixes see http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc2.html

Hope that helps.

**Update:**
If you don't want to set a fixed stroke-width, but *add* something to the stroke-width, the following change will do the job:

1. remove the unit (px) from the xsl:param value, so it reads `<xsl:param name="stroke-width">1</xsl:param>`
2. add a new variable just after the existing ones: `<xsl:variable name="current" select="substring-before($rest,';')"/>`
3. replace the `select` attribute of the `xsl:value-of` tag with `$current + $stroke-width`, so it looks like: `<xsl:value-of select="$current + $stroke-width"/>`

This assumes that there is no unit after `stroke-width:`in the source SVG. In order to be added, both the old value and the increment must be plain numbers.